# Pandas dataframe dump to excel with color formatting

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a large pandas dataframe `df` as:

```
Sou ATC   P25   P75 Avg
A   11    9     15  10
B   6.63  15    15  25
C   6.63  5     10  8
```

I want to print this datamframe to excel file but I want to apply formatting to each row of the excel file such that following rules are applied to cells in `ATC` and `Avg` columns:

- colored in red if value is less than P25
- colored in green if value is greater than P75
- colored in yellow if value is between P25 and P75

Sample display in excel is as follows:

[image]

I am not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`style.Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) with `DataFrame of styles` with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for filling by masks created by [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) and 
[`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html):

```
def color(x): 
   c1 = 'background-color: red'
   c2 = 'background-color: green'
   c3 = 'background-color: yellow'
   c = ''

   cols = ['ATC','Avg']
   m1 = x[cols].lt(x['P25'], axis=0)
   m2 = x[cols].gt(x['P75'], axis=0)
   arr = np.select([m1, m2], [c1, c2], default=c3)

   df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=x.index, columns=cols)
   return df1.reindex(columns=x.columns, fill_value=c)

df.style.apply(color,axis=None).to_excel('format_file.xlsx', index=False, engine='openpyxl')
```

[image: pic]