# Pandas dataframe to excel with color formatting using ExcelWriter and left alignment

Tags: pandas, python-3.8, pandas.excelwriter

There is an answer to similar problem at another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61649824/pandas-dataframe-dump-to-excel-with-color-formatting).But I am looking to learn this using `Pandas ExcelWriter`

I have a large pandas dataframe `df` as:

```
Sou ATC   P25   P75 Avg
A   11    9     15  10
B   6.63  15    15  25
C   6.63  5     10  8
```

I want to print this datamframe to excel file but I want to apply formatting to each row of the excel file such that following rules are applied to cells in `ATC` and `Avg` columns:

- colored in red if value is less than P25
- colored in green if value is greater than P75
- colored in yellow if value is between P25 and P75

Sample display in excel is as follows:

[image]

Please note the **left aligned** display of `column A`. I am also interested in learning how I can use `ExcelWriter` to left align the output to excel.

A started code that I am using right now is:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\outfile.xlx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='mysheet', index=False)
worksheet = writer.sheets['mysheet']
```

I am not sure how to approach this beyond the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `style`:

```
def hightlighter(x):
    return np.select((x<df['P25'], x>df['P75']), 
              ('background-color: red', 'background-color: green'),
              'background-color: yellow')
def align(x):
    return ['text-align:left']*len(x)

(df.style
   .apply(hightlighter, subset=['ATC','Avg'])
   .apply(align, subset=['Source'])
   .to_excel(writer, sheet_name='mysheet', index=False, freeze_panes=(1,0))
)
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't use ExcelWriter though?

Comment: I generally found ExcelWriter a bit redundant. I would simplify thing and let `pandas` handle the writing in the background. Anyway, see updated answer.

Comment: I also don't see left alignment for column A output

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to ask or maybe I can start another thread. Is there a way to freeze the first row and first column using style? I know how to do it using ExcelWriter.

Comment: Actually, you can try adding with option `freeze_panes=(1, 0)` to `to_excel(...)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang - Is there anyway to read an excel with color formatting and then convert to df.to_html()?