# Wrap text in whole column using dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

How to wrap text for all columns?

[image]

I tried like this but didn't work:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

What I expected:

[image]

As I mentioned above, it should work for all columns in dataframe. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

refer to the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html) document here

```
# import alignment
from openpyxl.styles import   Alignment

#set active sheet
sheet_obj = xl.active

# apply the alignment style to each of the cell in your desired_col. col D in this example
for cell in sheet_obj["D:D"]:
    cell.alignment=Alignment(wrap_text=True)
```

Comment: Hi! You mean `openpyxl.styles.alignment.Alignment(wrap_text=True)`? If yes, where exactly I should put this line?

Comment: Hi again @Naveed! It seems not working but maybe I'm doing something wrong. I put above line before writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine="openpyxl").

Comment: ok, no problem:-)

Comment: Hmm, if I understand it well sheet_obj it just "sheet" in my code and "D:D" it "column:column"? I'm asking because I'm not sure how to adapt your solution to my code. In my code `print(column)` return name of columns: "Name", "Surname" etc., `print(sheet)` return "family" and `print(dataframe[column]` return <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
-> https://snipboard.io/5jwbhQ.jpg

Comment: there might be another way, with this answer, one needs to read-in the excel, apply the style and update the excel. Makes sense?

Comment: does this helps?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150078/python-using-pandas-to-format-excel-cell

Comment: If there is no other way, excel may be reopen but it will be big problem for large files, like 20mb?

Comment: does this help ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61665580/pandas-dataframe-to-excel-with-color-formatting-using-excelwriter-and-left-align

Comment: Will try tomorrow, let you know :-)